# Request a solution to Error: File pubspec.yaml could not be found

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.